# Joins With CommonTable Expression - Sql

Tags: sql, t-sql

The Feedback table is like this

```
URL            DeveloperStatus   ReviewerStatus
---------------------------------------------------------
default.aspx    Open                 Closed
default.aspx    Open                 Open
Pages.aspx      Closed               Open
Pages.aspx      Open                 Closed
Pages.aspx      Closed               Closed
```

Each url can be listed multiple times and its DStatus & Rstatus can be Open/Closed irrelevant of each other's status

I would like to list a summary like this:

```
URL            DeveloperStatus   ReviewerStatus
---------------------------------------------------------
default.aspx    Open                 Open
Pages.aspx      Open                 Open
```

If a url has atleast one DeveloperStatus as Open, then it should be Open. Same for ReveiwerStatus.

This is my working code. How can I improve this:

```
;WITH TBL1 AS
(
SELECT URL, DeveloperStatus,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY URL ORDER BY DeveloperStatus DESC) AS rn
FROM Feedback
)
,TBL2 AS
(
SELECT URL, ReviewerStatus,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY URL ORDER BY ReviewerStatus DESC) AS rn
FROM Feedback
)
SELECT DISTINCT f.URL,TBL1.DeveloperStatus,TBL2.ReviewerStatus FROM Feedback f
LEFT JOIN TBL1 ON f.URL = TBL1.URL AND TBL1.rn=1
LEFT JOIN TBL2 ON f.URL = TBL2.URL AND TBL2.rn=1
```

Answer (score 1):

If I didn't misunderstand your question. I could do that with aggregration.

```
select Url, Max(DeveloperStatus), Max(ReviewerStatus) 
from YourTable 
Group by Url
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.. It only allows for two statuses, open and closed.

```
SELECT DISTINCT  
        URL
       ,DeveloperStatus = CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Feedback x WHERE x.URL = f.URL and x.DeveloperStatus = 'Open') THEN 'Open' ELSE 'Closed' END
       ,ReviewerStatus = CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Feedback x WHERE x.URL = f.URL and x.ReviewerStatus = 'Open') THEN 'Open' ELSE 'Closed' END
FROM Feedback f
```

Could also do this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.FeedBack (
     URL VARCHAR(30)
    ,DeveloperStatus VARCHAR(20)
    ,ReviewerStatus VARCHAR(20)
    );

SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO dbo.FeedBack (URL, DeveloperStatus, ReviewerStatus)
    SELECT 'default.aspx' AS URL,    'Open' AS DeveloperStatus,                 'Closed' AS ReviewerStatus
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'default.aspx',    'Open',                 'Open'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Pages.aspx',     'Closed',               'Open'
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'Pages.aspx',     'Open',                 'Closed'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Pages.aspx',     'Closed',               'Closed'

SELECT DISTINCT 
       f.URL
      ,DeveloperStatus = ISNULL(df.DeveloperStatus,f.DeveloperStatus)
      ,ReviewerStatus = ISNULL(rf.ReviewerStatus, f.ReviewerStatus)     
FROM FeedBack f
LEFT JOIN FeedBack df ON f.URL = df.URL and df.DeveloperStatus = 'Open'
LEFT JOIN FeedBack rf ON f.URL = rf.URL and rf.ReviewerStatus = 'Open'


DROP TABLE FeedBack
```